# List of Android OS UI component package names

Tags: android

In the app I'm building, I have to deal with package names, and need the ability to ignore certain ones: `"com.android.app.launcher"`, `"com.android.inputmethod"`, etc (basically anything from the core OS). Is there a list of these package names somewhere? In addition, do these package names vary per Android version?

Comment: "Is there a list of these package names somewhere?" -- no. Partly, that is because you have provided any sort of criteria for what would be on the list (is it "package names that have an 'a' in them"?). I assume that you think that "Android OS UI component" is the criteria, but you have not defined what "Android OS UI component" means. Partly, that is because the list of installed packages varies by device and user.

Comment: Well... I know I'm Captain Obvious, but what about skipping the strings which start with `com.android.`?

Answer (score 0):

List of all packages may be probably in OS source, e.g. [your `com.android.inputmethod`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/inputmethod/). You may also use search [like for your `com.android.app.launcher`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/inputmethod/) to inspect how it was "changing" (launcher2, launcher3 - new packages and new references) during Android versioning (so yes, may vary... somehow)